# How to make my imageview rotate to center of view in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have clock application in which I have added custom images to the clock hands (minute and hour). When I run the application, my minute hand rotate properly in the clockwise but the problem is the imageview does not rotate around the center of the view; it rotates around itself.

```
#import "AnalogClocktestViewController.h"

@implementation AnalogClocktestViewController

#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <QuartzCore/CALayer.h>
#import <QuartzCore/CoreAnimation.h>

@synthesize digitalswitch;
@synthesize hourimage;
@synthesize minuteimage;
@synthesize backimage;
@synthesize clockLabel;


- (void) showActivity {
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |
    NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit| NSMinuteCalendarUnit
    |NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:date];
    int h = [comps hour];
    int m = [comps minute];

    time_hour = h * 30*-1;
    time_minut = m * 6*-1;
        CGAffineTransform cgaRotateHr  =
    CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(time_hour);
    CGAffineTransform cgaRotateMin =
    CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(time_minut);

    //Looks awful but it works (PNGs with transparency have blocked edges)
    [hourimage setTransform:cgaRotateHr];
//hourimage is the imageview for hourhand of clock
    [minuteimage setTransform:cgaRotateMin];
//minuteimage is the imageview for minute hand of clock.


    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [clockLabel setText:[formatter stringFromDate:date]];
}




-(void)startClockUpdates
{
    [self showActivity];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(showActivity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self startClockUpdates];

}







- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: you need to make a combination of translation and rotation to achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An addition to Alex's answer -

If your image looks like this:

```
_________
|   ^   |
|   |   |
|   |   |
|___0___|
```

Make it look like this:

```
_________
|   ^   |
|   |   |
|   |   |
|   0   |
|       |
|       |
|_______|
```

So that the center of the clock hand is in the center of the image. Then, it should rotate around the center.

Comment: thanks this problem is solved i have another problem when my clock hand start rotating it takes a lap of 2 seconds everytime and when it is to reach 60 sec that is when it starts rotating from 59 sec it takes a lap of 20 sec.What may be the problem.Please help me in solving this problem.Thanks

Comment: First of all, your wording is confusing. Secondly, as that is another question, please ask it in a separate question on Stack Overflow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an image that is twice the size, and has alpha on the other side, therefore would be appear to rotate around the center.

Comment: Alex i want my imageview to rotate on center as well as its x axis should be fixed at the center of uiview

Comment: what do you mean? - if you want to create a standard analog clock surely all you have to do is in an image editor, increase the canvas size of the image to 2X, move the hand so it's it goes from the centre of the image, to the outisde, and in IB position it to the center of your view, then in code rotate it?